# Don't understand how sscanf() function works

Tags: c++, parsing, file-io, scanf

I don't understand how to use `sscanf()` in C++ for reading from a file.

I'm working on a program that reads three names of runners from a file, along with each of their five best times. I want to average out each runner's times and say who the best runner is. I am having the absolute hardest time with file IO.

Cplusplus.com has helped some, but doesn't really say how to read off, separate the char* (names) from the floats (times), etc. Elsewhere, I can't escape jargon and explanations that are too technical.

A friend showed me this code snippet to explain.

```
while(file>>str) {
    sscanf (str.c_str(),"%d",&myint);
}
```

Anyone mind explaining to me how it's read?

Comment: In C++, don't use `sscanf()`.  It's a C function, with constraints imposed on it by C.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler what would you use instead? regex?

Comment: Try Logo maybe. Even professionals have trouble with C sometimes.

Comment: sscanf(this string is formatted into, this format, and save to this string)

Comment: @Gir: iostreams are more powerful than sscanf, and simpler to use

Answer (score 5):

Using `sscanf()` is considered a bit old school, but can be very beneficial and is worth mastering.  I think you're looking for something like:

```
sscanf(input, "%s %f", name, &time);
```

where `input` is a line from the file.  Some of the basics are `%s` for the basic string and `%f` for the float.

Enjoy the start of your programming; it only gets better as you gain experience.

Answer (score 1):

scanf if the opposite of printf.

The first "s" in "sscanf" means it scans a string. "fscanf" scans a file, and "scanf" scans the standard input.

the formatting is the same as printf.

if `sprintf(s, "%d x", 5)` prints "5 x" into s than `sscanf("5 x", "%d x", &n)` will place 5 into n. It's allways the opposite of printf.

The exception is `%s`. `%s` in printf prints EVERY string. printf("%s", str); WILL print str, no matter what's in str. In scanf, `%s` is a word. A word is something without spaces. so reading a `%s` will only read a word.

`sscanf(str, "%d", &a);` means str has a format of "%d" (a single decimal number), and you are reaing this number to a (because &a is the second argument).

As an example

```
int a,b,c,d;
sscanf("10,20,30,40", "%d,%d,%d,%d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
```

will result in a = 10, b = 20, c= 30, d = 40. each %d will read to the next argument, and each will read a single decimal number.

Answer (score 1):

Overall, the [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html) function is used to convert a (C) string into a series of values in program variables under the guidance of a format string which describes the values to be found in the string.

Dissecting the quoted code:

```
while (file >> str)
{
    sscanf(str.c_str(), "%d", &myint);
}
```

We can assume that `file` is an input stream and `str` is a string.  The `while` loop reads one 'word' from the input into the string on each iteration, where a 'word' is a series of non-white space characters, possibly preceded by a series of white space characters.

The `sscanf()` statement in the example has three arguments and a return value which is ignored (rather at your peril).  The first argument is a C style string, so the word that was read is converted to a C string with the `str.c_str()` call.  The second argument is a format string which tells `sscanf()` what to expect in the string.  In this case, the `%d` conversion specifier indicates a decimal integer.  The third argument is a pointer to the corresponding type, where the converted value will be stored.  In general, a format string can contain a number of conversion specifiers, and there needs to be one pointer argument for each conversion specifier that assigns (you can skip data by suppressing the assignment).

The return value from `sscanf()` is the number of successful assigning conversions.  In this case, you should be checking that you got one conversion completed.

Here is a working miniature program based on your example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

static void read_stuff(std::istream &file)
{
    std::string str;
    while (file >> str)
    {
        std::cout << "IN: <<" << str << ">>" << std::endl;
        int myint;
        if (sscanf(str.c_str(), "%d", &myint) != 1)
        {
            std::cerr << "Oops: sscanf() failed" << std::endl;
            std::exit(1);
        }
        std::cout << "GOT: " << myint << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    read_stuff(std::cin);
    return(0);
}
```

Suppose you type the input line: `123 234 345 abc`.  Then the program produces:

```
IN: <<123>>
GOT: 123
IN: <<234>>
GOT: 234
IN: <<345>>
GOT: 345
IN: <<abc>>
Oops: sscanf() failed
```

Note that if the names you are dealing with contain first name and surname, possibly with middle initial, and with 5 numbers (all on a single line), then you probably need a different process.  You'd likely use `getline()` to read a whole line, and then attempt to parse it with `sscanf()` (or perhaps you'd use a `stringstream` instead).  You'd have to deal with fewer than 5 numbers on the line, of course.  I/O is always tricky, especially when you have to deal with erroneous data too (and production-quality code always has to be ready to deal with erroneous data).

Comment: +1 for emphasizing the importance of checking the return value--something oddly missing from all of the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you specify a string format in second argument to sscanf function substituting variables you want to
parse with placeholders.

Say, you know that your file consists of following lines:

```
Father bought 8 bottles of rum on day 1.  
Father bought 11 bottles of rum on day 2.  
Father bought 5 bottles of rum on day 3.  
Father bought 19 bottles of rum on day 4.
```

You don't care about anything in that string other than amount of bottles for each day.
You fix the parts that do not change, i.e. "Father bought bottles of rum on day"
and specify a placeholder for parts that you want to extract from the string.

Your code would look like that:

```
int nDay, nBottles;
sscanf(str.c_str(), "Father bought %d bottles of rum on day %d", &nBottles, &nDay);
cout << "Day: " << nDay << ", bottles: " << nBottles << endl;
```

The symbol after % just specifies the type of variable that part would be parsed to. `d` here means decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `sscanf(str.c_str(), "%d", &myint)` instead of `sscanf(str, "%d", &myint)`.

I see the others explained about `sscanf`, but I think your question is a little bit different.

`sscanf` is a C function, but you can use it in C++ because C++ includes C. `sscanf` basicly takes a string, divide it as you will show and then assign these parts to variables. But there is no such a thing called `string` in C. Because of this, `sscanf` takes its parameter as `char*` namely `char pointer` which basicly do the same job with `string`.

In C++, you should use `c_str()` function to convert `string` to `char pointer`.